# How to upload a file in SQL Server DB using Java and Spring MVC

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, spring-mvc, file-upload

I have jsp with `method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">` in form tag, Spring MVC Controller with `@RequestParam CommonsMultipartFile otherDocs,` and below piece of code to insert file into DB

```
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

        try {
            String fileName = fileItem.getName().substring(fileItem.getName().lastIndexOf("\\")+1, fileItem.getName().length());

            File file = new File(fileItem.getName());
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

            String sql = "INSERT INTO MyTable(formId, fileType, fileName, updateTime, updateUser, content) VALUES(?, ?, ?, getDate(), ?, ?)";

            pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);          

            pstmt.setInt(1, id);
            int len = (int)file.length();

            if(fileItem.getContentType().endsWith(".document")){
                pstmt.setString(2, "Document");
            }else{
                pstmt.setString(2, "else");             
            }
            pstmt.setString(3, fileName);
            pstmt.setString(4, userLoggedIn);

            //pstmt.setBytes(5, bs);<------noted
            pstmt.setBinaryStream(5, fis, len);

            int count = pstmt.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception e) {             
            e.printStackTrace();            
        }finally{
            try {
                pstmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

I am getting "**String or binary data would be truncated.**" after firing executeUpdate() only when 5th parameter is set. I have tried running the query without 5th parameter which is running fine.

I tried with commented "noted" line as well, getting the same Data Truncation error.

Thanks

Jai

Comment: You would require to use blob or clob to save it in DB or if you want something simple, then use byte-array. I have no idea about SQL server, but I would recommend saving files on disk with an identifier randomly created and then saving the identifier and path in DB. If you like this approach, I can provide you a solution.

Comment: I cant use the approach that you are suggesting. I am using SQL Server with "content" as varbinary data type. Thanks for comment.

Comment: Ok. Enjoy. Lemme know if there is a peoblem.

Comment: I tried to fetch definition of my table in that its showing "CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH" as 1. I think it should be -1. Any guess?

Comment: No idea about SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a alot better solution if you save the file extern in a directory with its hash or something like that as name, in the database you should only save its name afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, will implement that way. But I am not facing any issue because of that. Please tell me what to do for, what I am facing now?

Answer (score 0):

Database table's column was required to be changed from varbinary to varbianry(max). This change made my code to work :)